# Issue in shrinking and then dismissing UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom view which I present with animation giving a bouncing effect. Now, I want it to disappear in the similar fashion like shrink and then disappear.

The below piece of code to present my view with a bouncing effect is working fine:

```
self.componentDetailController.view.center = iGestureRecognizer.view.center;
self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 0.0;
self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);

 [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.2) animations:^{
     self.componentDetailController.view.center = CGPointMake(kScreenWidth / 2, kScreenHeight / 2);
     self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 0.5;
     self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
 } completion:^(BOOL iFinished) {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.1) animations:^{
         self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 0.90;
         self.componentDetailController.view.center = CGPointMake(kScreenWidth / 2, kScreenHeight / 2);
         self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.98, 0.98);
     } completion:^(BOOL iFinished) {
         self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 1.0;
         self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
         self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
     }];
 }];
```

I have written the below piece of code to shrink and dismiss the view which is not working. It brings the view to the front a little but then does not dismiss it. Any clue what is wrong here:

```
 - (void)cancelButtonPressed {
    self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.1) animations:^{
        self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 1.0;
        self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
    } completion:^(BOOL iFinished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.4) animations:^{
            self.componentDetailController.view.center = self.tappedComponentView.center;
            self.componentDetailController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
            self.componentDetailController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.componentDetailController.view.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL iFinished) {
            [self.componentDetailController.view removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }];

    self.componentDetailController = nil;
    [self enableBackView];
}
```

Here, self.tappedComponentView.center is same as self.tappedComponentView.center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` call returns immediately, so as soon as the second animation runs, `self.componentDetailController` is `nil` and all the subsequent view-transformation calls go nowhere. Store `self.componentDetailController.view` into its own variable and reference that in your animation blocks. E.g.:

```
UIView *detailView = self.componentDetailController.view;
detailView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    detailView.alpha = 1;
// …
}];

self.componentDetailController = nil;
```

Comment: heh, just spotted this, started to type but you were a lot quicker. +1

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was under assumption that code will execute sequentially and that self.componentDetailController = nil; will get execute once the whole animation is done.